# Why am I getting a syntax error in this bash command on parentheses printf and calculator function?

Tags: bash, math, syntax, bc

Why am I getting an error with the ( in this line of script?

```
printf "%.3f\n" "$(bc -l <<< ($sum / $total))"
```

Error:

```
solution.sh: command substitution: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
solution.sh: command substitution: line 11: `bc -l <<< ($sum / $total))"'
```

The desired behavior is to take a numerical variables $sum and $total and perform division on them, then print out the value to 3 decimal points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `bc -l` needs input as a single string but `($sum / $total)` is unquoted and gets split into more than one word.

You may use:

```
printf "%.3f\n" "$(bc -l <<< "($sum / $total)")"
```

Comment: It is closer, though now it is throwing an error on standard in:
    (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: Are you using `bash`? When I use `sum=15; total=25; printf "%.3f\n" "$(bc -l <<< "($sum / $total)")"` I get `0.600`

Comment: Yes and no.  This is part of a problem from Hackerrank. [Link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---compute-the-average/problem)

Comment: Reading the discussion, I think it is a buggy problem set along with me mishandling reads.  Not related to the problem.  This works.

Comment: For the problem that you linked can be solved by using `sum=0; total=; while read num; do [[ -z $total ]] && total=$num || ((sum += num)); done < file; printf "%.3f\n" "$(bc -l <<< "($sum / $total)")"`

Answer (score 1):

Better do it like below. It would be more clear

```
result=$(bc -l <<< ($sum / $total))
printf "%.3f\n" "$result"
```